# Cannot update the timestamp of a file twice

Tags: file

I have a File and I process each row of a file. Before opening the file I change the timestamp of that .txt file to currentTimestamp.

After opening the file and processing each line I try to change the currentTimestamp of the .txt file being processed. But the update happens only at the time of opening the file.

Please suggest how to update the timestamp after each row is processed.

Comment: Why do you need to change the timestamp so frequently? Does your processing take long enough that the timestamp actually can change? If you finish in <1 second, you'll likely never see a change.

Comment: I want to change the timestamp after everyline since there are more than 10000 lines in my .txt file and there is a thread which puts this .txt file into another directory if its last modified timestamp is more than 1 hour old.

Answer (score 0):

Sachin,
 You didn't mention which technology are you using (C#, Java, VB etc.,)

Try the following solution and see if that helps.

1. Open the file change the timestamp start processing the lines one by one
2. After configured amount of line got processed. Store the line index in memory. close the file and reopen the file. now you can change the timestamp as per your statement. Start processing from the previously processed index+1. Continue this until you finish all lines.